# How do I create an object in TimerTask in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make the canvas draw some pictures in a fixed period of time. It's like an item showing on the screen and it disappears after 5 seconds. Then after another 3 seconds, a new item is drawn and last for another 5 seconds.
I used Timer and TimerTask as below

```
    public class PowerUpMaking extends TimerTask{
        public void run() {
              test = 1;
              powerUp = new Powerup(players.get("player1"),getHeight());                
        }
    }
```

I declared powerUp in the constructor. Whole thing is in a class that extends View.
What I want to do is just to create a new object for the reference variable.
It turns out the first line is working but the second line is not by checking the log.
How am I supposed to deal with this situation?
Many many thanks if anyone can help. First time to ask a question here actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not specifically sure what your error is: you should paste the logs so we can better determine what's going on.

If you're creating objects within a nested class you have to make sure that everything needed to create the object is available: is `players` an instance variable? Is it null when you are trying to create the object? Are you getting a `NullPointerException` from `players.get` or from `getHeight()`? Without the error logs it is very difficult to get the right answer.